# Font (texture)Open Gl minecraft blury

Tags: java, opengl, fonts, minecraft

Im trying to render a tff font in minecraft (Costum Font renderer). But the probelm is, that the font sides are blury or blocky. Help me.

```
package de.simpleclient.gui.font2;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.BufferOverflowException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ReadOnlyBufferException;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlStateManager;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public final class TextureHelper {

    public static int loadTexture(BufferedImage image) {


        int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 4);

        try {
            for(int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
                for(int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
                    int pixel = pixels[h * image.getWidth() + w];

                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));
                    buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));
                }
            }
            buffer.flip();
        } catch (BufferOverflowException | ReadOnlyBufferException ex) {return -1;}

        int textureID = GlStateManager._genTexture();
        GlStateManager._bindTexture(textureID);
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL30.GL_NEAREST );
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL30.GL_LINEAR);
        GL30.glTexImage2D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGBA, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        //GlStateManager._bindTexture(0);

        return textureID;
    }

}
```

```
package de.simpleclient.gui.font2.simplified;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.common.AbstractFont;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.common.Lang;


public final class TextFont extends AbstractFont {

    private final float stretching, spacing, lifting;

    public TextFont(String fileName, int size, float stretching, float spacing, float lifting, Lang lang) {
        Font font = getFont(fileName, Font.PLAIN, size);
        FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(font.getTransform() , true, true);

        double maxWidth = 0;
        double maxHeight = 0;

        int[] codes = lang.getCharCodes();
        char[] chars = new char[(codes[1] - codes[0] + codes[3] - codes[2])];

        int n = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d += 2) {
            for(int i = codes[d]; i <= codes[d + 1] - 1; i++) {
                chars[n] = (char) i;
                Rectangle2D bound = font.getStringBounds(Character.toString(chars[n]), fontRenderContext);
                maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, bound.getWidth());
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, bound.getHeight());
                n++;
            }
        }

        int d = (int)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((maxHeight + 2) * (maxWidth + 2) * chars.length));

        this.stretching = stretching;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.lifting = lifting;
        this.fontName = font.getFontName(Locale.ENGLISH);
        this.fontHeight = (float)(maxHeight / 2);
        this.imgHeight = d;
        this.imgWidth = d;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = setupGraphics(image, font);

        FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();

        int posX = 0;
        int posY = 1;

        for (char c : chars) {
            Glyph glyph = new Glyph();
            Rectangle2D bounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(Character.toString(c), graphics);
            glyph.width = (int)bounds.getWidth() + 1;
            glyph.height = (int)bounds.getHeight() + 2;

            if (posX + glyph.width >= imgWidth) {
                posX = 1;
                posY += maxHeight + fontMetrics.getDescent() + 2;
            }

            glyph.x = posX;
            glyph.y = posY;

            graphics.drawString(Character.toString(c), posX, posY + fontMetrics.getAscent());

            posX += glyph.width + 4;
            glyphs.put(c, glyph);

        }

        RenderSystem.recordRenderCall(() -> setTexture(image));
    }

    public float getStretching() {
        return stretching;
    }

    public float getSpacing() {
        return spacing;
    }

    public float getLifting() {
        return fontHeight + lifting;
    }

}
```

```
package de.simpleclient.gui.font2.common;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlStateManager;


import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.BufferBuilder;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.DefaultVertexFormat;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.Tesselator;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.VertexFormat;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.TemplateMod;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.TextureHelper;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.Wrapper;
import de.simpleclient.gui.shader.util.render.ShaderHelper;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer;
import org.joml.Matrix4f;

import static com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlConst.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlConst.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;


public abstract class AbstractFont implements Wrapper {
    
    protected final Map<Character, Glyph> glyphs = new HashMap<>();
    protected int texId, imgWidth, imgHeight;
    protected float fontHeight;
    protected String fontName;
    
    public abstract float getStretching();
    
    public abstract float getSpacing();
    
    public abstract float getLifting();
    
    public float getFontHeight() {
        return fontHeight;
    }
    
    public final String getFontName() {
        return fontName;
    }
    
    protected final void setTexture(BufferedImage img) {
        texId = TextureHelper.loadTexture(img);
    }
    
    public final void bindTex() {
        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, texId);

    }

    public final void unbindTex() {
        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, 0);


    }
    
    public static final Font getFont(String fileName, int style, int size) {
        String path = TemplateMod.FONT_DIR.concat(fileName);
        Font font = null;
        
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, TemplateMod.class.getResourceAsStream(path)).deriveFont(style, size);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        
        return font;
    }
    
    public final Graphics2D setupGraphics(BufferedImage img, Font font) {
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        boolean antiAlias = true;
        boolean fractionalMetrics = true;
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        return graphics;
    }
    
    // color components should be in range [0;1]


    public float renderGlyph(Matrix4f matrix, char c, float x, float y, float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
        Glyph glyph = glyphs.get(c);
        
        if (glyph == null) 
            return 0;

        float pageX = glyph.x / (float) imgWidth;
        float pageY = glyph.y / (float) imgHeight;
        float pageWidth = glyph.width / (float) imgWidth;
        float pageHeight = glyph.height / (float) imgHeight;
        float width = glyph.width + getStretching();
        float height = glyph.height;
        RenderSystem.setShader(GameRenderer::getPositionColorTexShader);
        BUILDER.begin(VertexFormat.Mode.QUADS, DefaultVertexFormat.POSITION_COLOR_TEX);
        BUILDER.vertex(matrix, x, y + height, 0).color(red, green, blue, alpha)
                .uv(pageX, pageY + pageHeight).endVertex();
        BUILDER.vertex(matrix, x + width, y + height, 0).color(red, green, blue, alpha)
                .uv(pageX + pageWidth, pageY + pageHeight).endVertex();
        BUILDER.vertex(matrix, x + width, y, 0).color(red, green, blue, alpha)
                .uv(pageX + pageWidth, pageY).endVertex();
        BUILDER.vertex(matrix, x, y, 0).color(red, green, blue, alpha)
                .uv(pageX, pageY).endVertex();
        TESSELLATOR.end();

        return width + getSpacing();
    }
    
    public float getWidth(char ch) {
        return glyphs.get(ch).width + getStretching();
    }
    
    public float getWidth(String text) {
        float width = 0.0f;
        float sp = getSpacing();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            width += getWidth(text.charAt(i)) + sp;
        }
        
        return (width - sp) / 2f;
    }
    
    public class Glyph {
        
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int width;
        public int height;
        
    }

}
```

```
package de.simpleclient.gui.font2.simplified;

import java.awt.Color;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.PoseStack;
import de.simpleclient.gui.font2.Wrapper;

import de.simpleclient.gui.shader.util.render.ShaderHelper;
import net.minecraft.util.FastColor;
import org.joml.Matrix4f;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlStateManager;

import static com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlConst.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlConst.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;


public final class SimplifiedFontRenderer implements Wrapper {

    public static float drawString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderString(matrices, font, text, x, y, color);
    }
    
    public static float drawCenteredXString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderString(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y, color);
    }

    public static float drawCenteredYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderString(matrices, font, text, x, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color);
    }
    
    public static float drawCenteredXYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderString(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color);
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x, y, color, getShadowColor(color));
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredXString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y, color, getShadowColor(color));
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color, getShadowColor(color));
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredXYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color, getShadowColor(color));
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color, Color shadowColor) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x, y, color, shadowColor);
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredXString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color, Color shadowColor) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y, color, shadowColor);
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color, Color shadowColor) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color, shadowColor);
    }
    
    public static float drawShadowedCenteredXYString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color, Color shadowColor) {
        return renderStringWithShadow(matrices, font, text, x - font.getWidth(text) / 2.0f, y + font.getLifting() / 2.0f + 0.5f, color, shadowColor);
    }
    
    private static float renderStringWithShadow(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color, Color shadowColor) {
        renderString(matrices, font, text, x + 1.0F, y, shadowColor);
        return renderString(matrices, font, text, x, y -= 1.0f, color) + 1.0f;
    }

    // returns string width

    private static float renderString(PoseStack matrices, TextFont font, String text, double x, double y, Color color) {
        y -= font.getLifting();
        int color1 = color.getRGB();
        float alpha = (float) FastColor.ARGB32.alpha(color1) / 255.0F;
        float red = (float)FastColor.ARGB32.red(color1) / 255.0F;
        float green = (float)FastColor.ARGB32.green(color1) / 255.0F;
        float blue = (float)FastColor.ARGB32.blue(color1) / 255.0F;

        float startPos = (float) x * 2f;
        float posX = startPos;
        float posY = (float) y * 2f;

        

        matrices.pushPose();
        
        //RenderSystem.enableBlend();




        GL30.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GlStateManager._blendFuncSeparate(770, 771, 1, 0);
        GlStateManager._blendFunc(770, 771);


        //RenderSystem.enableColorLogicOp();
        //RenderSystem.enableCull();
        //RenderSystem.enableDepthTest();

        matrices.scale(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);

        Matrix4f matrix = matrices.last().pose();

        font.bindTex();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            posX += font.renderGlyph(matrix, text.charATextFontt(i), posX, posY, red, green, blue, alpha);
        }
        
        font.unbindTex();

        matrices.popPose();
        RenderSystem.disableBlend();
        RenderSystem.disableDepthTest();
        //RenderSystem.disableColorLogicOp();
        RenderSystem.disableCull();
        GL30.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        return (posX - startPos) / 2.0f;
    }
    
    public static Color getShadowColor(Color color) {
        return new Color((color.getRGB() & 16579836) >> 2 | color.getRGB()  & -16777216);
    }

}
```

I tried much with this:

`GL30.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND); GlStateManager._blendFuncSeparate(770, 771, 1, 0); GlStateManager._blendFunc(770, 771);`

[image: Blocky uggly look]

[image: Smooth Blury]

It changes the look but it isnt perfect, every time the blur / unsharphnes, or block buggy look.
The Problem coud also be in the Texturehelper. I changed GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST but then it gets also blocky.

`GlStateManager._bindTexture(textureID); GL11.glTexParameterf(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL30.GL_LINEAR); GL11.glTexParameterf(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL30.GL_LINEAR); GL30.glTexImage2D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGBA, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer); GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D); //GlStateManager._bindTexture(0);`

Comment: Are you sure that your source texture image generated is sharp?

Comment: How Should I check that?

Comment: Testing the quality of a font texture without scaling can be done by rendering the font at its original dimensions, ensuring that there is a 1:1 mapping between pixels in the texture and pixels on the screen. E.g. if a letter in the texture is 32x32, render on a textured rectangle with 32x32 pixels on screen.

Comment: [picture](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/b15ac73b-950a-41e6-bd3f-368ef3fdfa47) the quality is same bad without scaling anything

Comment: I changed now GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST, its now tot blury but its pixeled when the window is fullsized

Comment: I could fix it, thanks for your help.